# The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'tablename', database 'database_Name', schema 'SampleSchema'. in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, sql-grant

I was able to insert the data into the table, now suddenly I got this error where the identity element is being updated with a large negative wrong value and the insert operation is restricted.

Could someone let me know what the problem is?

Comment: Go ask your team members or your dba. You have a permissions issue. We can't tell you why the problem occurs now.

Comment: i encountered the problem as the data which is to be inserted in the column was incorrect..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are getting this error because the user is trying to insert data in SQL server does not have insert permission on the table. You can give permission **insert permission** using

```
GRANT Insert ON yourschemaname.yourtablename TO yourusername;  
GO
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: could i know how the permission are automatically changed.

Comment: permission should not changed automatically. someone changed or you had accessed with some other user.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do this (presumably) in SQL-Server (SSMS).

Right-click the table in SQL-Server and give INSERT permissions to the user:

**Right Click the table
Properties
Permissions
(if necessary) add the user or role
click on the user/role
permission insert, put a check-mark in the 'grant' box.**